# Code a slash command on Rocket.chat with Hubot

Tags: hubot, rocket.chat

I'd like to use a slash command on Rocket.chat with Hubot but I don't know how to do it. A slash command is defined with /command and is an executable, I mean you don't see the order on your screen, just the answer.

Is it possible to do it?

Answer (score 0):

By default /commands not Integrated will return a command not found.

Go-to Administration->Messages and toggle "Allow Unrecognized Slash Commands" to true